# Upsert is creating duplicate child records

Tags: apex, class

the 'upsert' is creating duplicates NRProducts. how can I make just an update? if the NRProduct is already there.

let me explain you, there two objects parent(purchase order, po) and chld(purchase order detail pod), in order to create the pod I need to provide po.id and NRPoducts. All this is handle by the code. At this point if there is a pod with this fields for example po=123, NRPoducts__c=0001, qty__c=4 and I make another upsert to the same pod, i want the system to identify if there is a NRProduct with the same id(NRProducts is a master-detail)if that us true i want to update the qty__c else insert new NRProduct
 thank you in advance!

```
public void cloneSelectedObjects2(){

SOStoupload = new List<Purchase_Order_Details__c>();

for (relatedObjects relatedObject : objectChildren) {
    List<relatedObjectRow> selectedRelatedRows = new List<relatedObjectRow>();

    for (relatedObjectRow row : relatedObject.objectRows) {
        if (row.selected) {
            selectedRelatedRows.add(row);
        } 
    }

    //here for loop to get values
    for (relatedObjectRow row : selectedRelatedRows) {

        //create new pODetails
        Purchase_Order_Details__c pod = new Purchase_Order_Details__c();

        pod.Purchase_Order__c = objecttext;
        pod.NRProducts__c = row.obj.get('Id');
        pod.Qty_NR__c = Decimal.valueOf(row.EnteredValue);


        SOStoupload.add(pod);

      }
  }

iupsert SOStoupload;  

}
```

Comment: When you say that it is creating duplicates, do you mean that the `pod.NRProducts__c` value should be unique across all `Purchase_Order_Details__c` records in the org? Or do you have other code which is inserting `NRProduct__c` records?

Comment: let me explain you, there two objects parent(purchase order, po) and chld(purchase order detail pod), in order to create the pod I need to provide po.id and NRPoducts. All this is handle by the code. At this point if there is a pod with this fields for example po=123, NRPoducts__c=0001, qty__c=4 and I make another upsert to the same pod, i want the system to identify if there is a NRProduct with the same id(NRProducts is a master-detail)if that us true i want to update the qty__c else insert new NRProduct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `upsert` operation has two behaviors, one with an external id field specified, and one without an external ID which uses the object ID values of the records to identify existing records.

In order to get the behavior you're looking for, your `Purchase_Order_Details__c` records need to have an external ID field which you can then use in your `upsert` call.

Create a new field on the Purchase_Order_Details__c object (`NewField__c` in the example below). Check the boxes for External Id and Unique on the new field. This field will contain a value that uniquely identifies a detail row, it appears that a good candidate for this would be the concatenated ID values of the PO and the NRProduct.

This field can be populated with a workflow rule and field update action that combines the text from the `Purchase_Order__c` & `NRProducts__c` fields on the `Purchase_Order_Details__c` record and updates your new field. You will need to populate this field on any existing records in your org.

Your code would then look similar to this:

```
public void cloneSelectedObjects2(){
    SOStoupload = new List<Purchase_Order_Details__c>();
    for (relatedObjects relatedObject : objectChildren) {
        List<relatedObjectRow> selectedRelatedRows = new List<relatedObjectRow>();
        for (relatedObjectRow row : relatedObject.objectRows) {
            if (row.selected) {
                selectedRelatedRows.add(row);
            } 
        }

        //here for loop to get values
        for (relatedObjectRow row : selectedRelatedRows) {

            //create new pODetails
            Purchase_Order_Details__c pod = new Purchase_Order_Details__c();

            pod.Purchase_Order__c = objecttext;
            pod.NRProducts__c = row.obj.get('Id');
            pod.Qty_NR__c = Decimal.valueOf(row.EnteredValue);

            // create the value that we are using as the external ID
            pod.NewField__c = pod.Purchase_Order__c + pod.NRProducts__c;

            SOStoupload.add(pod);
          }
      }

    // specify which field we are going to use for the upsert identification
    upsert SOStoupload NewField__c;  

}
```

Related Documentation: [Upsert Statement](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_upsert.htm)

Comment: Mark that made the magic... thank you so much for your help.